# NFT Smart Contract

Tags: nft, mint

I have created NFT tokens by using bellow command:

spl-token create-token --decimals 0 ntwze65k6HMR4LiKqeyBPbQGSqT4H4cBVXJEkLxid1N.json

spl-token create-account ntwze65k6HMR4LiKqeyBPbQGSqT4H4cBVXJEkLxid1N

spl-token mint ntwze65k6HMR4LiKqeyBPbQGSqT4H4cBVXJEkLxid1N 99666666666666

I am stuck where i should declare my NFTs and collections

Thanks for any possible help

Regards,

Comment: Lots of great answers already. If you're looking for a cli tool to directly mint NFTs, check out Metaplex's [sugar](https://developers.metaplex.com/candy-machine/sugar/getting-started). It lets you mint an nft using a config json file where you can specify stuff like the nft's collection address. It also has commands for creating and managing collections.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the Metaplex library for information about NFT collections and metadata. There is also a nice open source tool for doing most of the things you'd want via CLI: https://metaboss.rs

Answer (score 1):

What’s your use case? There’s a ton of great teams working on solutions that simplify using NFTs. Check out resources:

Metaplex: https://docs.metaplex.com/guides/

Underdog Protocol: https://underdog.readme.io/reference/getting-started-1

Answer (score 1):

depending on what u need to do in terms of the nft collection there are multiple approaches. from what u shared it looks like u just want to get an NFT collection/mint thingy working.

the best and quickest way to achieve this is to use metaplex and their sugar cli - it works like the solana cli does but will handle the contracts and everything needed for an NFT collection.

https://docs.metaplex.com/developer-tools/sugar/guides/sugar-for-cmv3

read through the info on the link above, and try thigns out using the examples, and go throguh them step by step. For a small amount of sol (<1SOL) u will be able to make a small nft collection.

Once you get sugar working, any questions on usage/problems dont hesitate to ask but this is the best way for what u want to do